# Why isn't the environment variable working in application.yml?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I have the following code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The Env Var is "+ ((System.getenv("DOCKER_IP") == null || System.getenv("DOCKER_IP").equals("")) ? "Not Defined" : System.getenv("DOCKER_IP")));
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
spring:
  cassandra:
    keyspace-name: "test"
    local-datacenter: "datacenter1"
    port: 9042
    contact-points:
      - ${DOCKER_IP}
```

When I run I see the ip in the console statement

> The Env Var is 192.168.56.101

But it tries to use 127.0.0.1...

> 2023-10-30T14:10:50.073-04:00  WARN 22688 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.o.d.internal.core.ContactPoints      : Ignoring invalid contact point ${DOCKER_IP}:9042 (unknown host ${DOCKER_IP})
> Suppressed: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:9042
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

Why is this happening and how do I get it to inject the value?

If I hardcode the value it works so this is my current workaround but I need this to work without the hardcoding.

Comment: Can you try this `contact-points: ${DOCKER_IP}`, some of the document said it's a string. Which version that you're using?

Comment: Darn I was hoping but nope same response. FTR I am using 4.17 of the datastax driver

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a bug, another approach is to override the default spring key

```
export SPRING-CASSANDRA-CONTACT-POINTS = 192.168.56.101
```